# PHPExcel, selecionar sheet ao importar dados para mysql

Tags: php, mysql, microsoft-excel, phpexcel

Quero importar dados de uma planilha mas da sheet 2 e não estou a conseguir.
Indiquei a sheet 2 (index 1) como ativa desta forma, mas sempre entra a sheet 1 (index 0):

**$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);**

O que estará incorreto?

Este é o código que estou a usar:

**SCRIPT A FUNCIONAR PARA IMPORTAÇÃO DE xlsx ESCOLHENDO A ABA (INDEX)**

```
<?php
     /** Error reporting */
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
     ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
     date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

     if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') 
     die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

     /** Include PHPExcel and MySQLi db */
     require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/DB.php';
     require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

     //Create DB object
     use DB\MySQLi;


     // Create new PHPExcel object
     $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("arquivo.xlsx");
     $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1); // aqui indica a aba que quer importar
     $dataArr = array();

     foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
         $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();
         $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
         $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(True); //varre todas as células
         foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
              $colIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($cell->getColumn());
              echo ('Linha: '.$rowIndex.' Coluna: '.$colIndex.' Valor: '.$cell->getValue());
              $val = $cell->getValue();
              $dataArr[$rowIndex][$colIndex] = $val;

         }
    }

      unset($dataArr[1]); 


      $hostname = 'localhost';
      $username = 'root';
      $password = '';
      $database = 'dbase';

      $db = new MySQLi($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

      foreach($dataArr as $val){
          $query = $db->query("INSERT INTO employees SET fname = '" . $db->escape($val['1']) . "', lname = '" . $db->escape($val['2']) . "', email = '" . $db->escape($val['3']) . "', phone = '" . $db->escape($val['4']) . "', company = '" . $db->escape($val['5']) . "'");
      }
```

Comment: Já tentou pegar dessa forma $worksheetTitle = $worksheet->getActiveSheet()->getTitle()?;

Comment: agora deu este erro: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::getWorksheetIterator() in line 25, esta linha: foreach ($objWorksheet->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {

Comment: Vou editar a resposta, mas getWorksheetIterator()  varre todas as abas se você quer pegar os dados apenas de uma por que ler as outras?

Comment: mas ele nao tem de varrer todas para encontrar o index indicado? se não, qual seria o metodo correto?

Comment: Não tinha entendido, você na verdade quer pegar os dados de todas as abas menos da 1ª é isso? Ou é de todas?

Comment: não @Nelson Aguiar, talvez eu esteja a confundir as coisas, vou clarificar.
eu quero pegar num xlsx com várias abas e importar para mysql só a aba 2 ou index 1.

Comment: no código acima, apresenta este erro:  Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::getWorksheetIterator() in import1.php on line 25. este metodo getWorksheetIterator() nao estácorreto, mas na minha ideia seria o que iria ver as abas existentes e selecionar a escolhida no setActiveSheetIndex(1) mas não está a resultar...  e é este erro que não estou a conseguir resolver.

Comment: Cara o complicado é que estou sem PHP aqui para testar isso, mas a principio mude o setActiveSheet(1), para getSheet(1) e use aquele foreach ali de da resposta para ver a saida

Comment: Nelson, usando as suas indicações, adicionei apenas estas 2 linhas no foreach $val = $cell->getValue(); $dataArr[$rowIndex][$colIndex] = $val; e já está a funcionar. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu!

Comment: Nelson, só mais uma duvida, se eu quiser indicar um limite de colunas, por exemplo 10 e aba tiver 14, como poderia fazer essa escolha coluna a coluna? Seria nesta linha $dataArr[$row][$col] = $val; ?

Comment: você pode fazer um if dentro do segundo foreach com a seguinte instrução if($colIndex > 9 ) break; ou implemtar PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter em sua classe, porém irá te dar um pouco mais de trabalho, mas ele já pegará os dados filtrando as colunas dá uma olhada aqui: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/05-Reader-Options.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para se trabalhar em abas ou sheets, como preferir, você deve usar, lembrando que a indexação das abas começam em 0:

```
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1);
```

ou alternativamente porém menos produtivo da forma que disse em meu comentário;

```
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
```

E ai pegar os dados dessa forma:

```
$worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getActiveSheet->getTitle();
```

ou:

```
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1).getActiveSheet();
```

Tente fazer dessa maneira no foreach:

```
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
  $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();
  $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
  $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(True); //varre todas as células
  foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    $colIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($cell->getColumn());
    echo ('Linha: '.$rowIndex.'Coluna: '.$colIndex.'Valor: '.$cell->getValue());

  }
}
```

Referência : [PHPExcel Developer Documentation
Worksheets](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/06-Worksheets.md)

Espero que ajude.